# Match particular numbers with regex

Tags: regex

I have lines like these:

```
1. 1-1-2-3-4-5-92-6-7-21-42-66 \54
2. 1-1-2-3-4-22-5-6-7-21-42-66 \2
...
```

With regex`\b(2)\b` i match:

1. 1-13-**2**-3-4-5-21-60-71-21-42-66 \54

**2**. 1-1-**2**-3-4-22-5-6-7-21-42-66 \**2**

But i only need to match:

1. 1-13-**2**-3-4-5-21-60-71-21-42-66 \54
2. 1-1-**2**-3-4-22-5-6-7-21-42-66 \2

How to do this with regex if it's possible?

Comment: Maybe [`(?<=-)2(?=-)`](https://regex101.com/r/fNe0YJ/1)? Or [`(?<![^-])2(?![^-])`](https://regex101.com/r/fNe0YJ/2)?

Comment: If your numbers are always separated by "-", use `-(2)-`. What language are you using?

Comment: @MarounMaroun said it right. That will accept/match "-2-" syntax in your string.

Comment: -(2)- would not match 3. 2-1-34-5 or 4. 4-56-53-2 where number not fully wrapped with '-'.

Comment: Actually, without more details - the regex flavor, how to deal with overlapping matches (e.g. `1-2-2-3`), are you extracting or replacing - it is difficult to provide the answer. Try [`(?<![^- ])2(?![^- ])`](https://regex101.com/r/fNe0YJ/3).

Comment: 2. 2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-212 \2
I want it to match all 2's except "2.", 2's in "212" and "\2"

Comment: So, please test [`(?<![^-\s])2(?![^-\s])`](https://regex101.com/r/fNe0YJ/4).

Comment: And yeah, it's works, thank you, Wiktor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<![^-\s])2(?![^-\s])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fNe0YJ/4).

**Details**:

- `(?<![^-\s])` -  a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a character other than `-` or whitespace before...
- `2` - a literal `2` char
- `(?![^-\s])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a character other than `-` or whitespace after `2`.

Comment: As I said. it would be better if you stated the regex flavor, how you want to deal with overlapping matches, and what you are doing: extracting or replacing. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/uFIDhm/2) showing how to replace the `2` with `9`.